# Get nested navigator screen route, hide tab bar

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to hide a tab bar in my nested navigator, how can I get the current nested route so I can hide the tab bar in the parent?

```
  <TabStack.Screen
        name={AppRoutes.MyVehicle.Name}
        listeners={() => ({
          ...
        })}
        options={({ route }) => {
          // get nested route name
          return {
            ...
            // tabBarStyle: set display none if certain route
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
              <AppTabBarIcon
                title="Vehicles"
                type="vehicles"
                isActive={focused}
              />
            ),
          };
        }}>
        {() => MyVehicleStackScreen()}
      </TabStack.Screen>
```